# jQuery sidebar accordion menu not working

Tags: jquery, menu, sidebar

My sidebar menu is not expanding on click. When you click menu item, submenu should drop down.

Here's link: http://jsfiddle.net/hv6jt8rn/

```
$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('hover', function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('href');
   var element = $(this).parent('li');
   if (element.hasClass('open')) {
      element.removeClass('open');
      element.find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
   }
   else {
      element.addClass('open');
      element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
      element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
      element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
   }
});
```

jQuery is included but still it isn't working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes):

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method,
>   which accepts one or two functions.

You can solve this by changing:

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('hover', function(){
//content
});
```

for

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').hover(function(){
//content
});
```

Check [working JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hv6jt8rn/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm truly grateful!

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated the answer with an explanation for this ... If you test your code with jquery 1.7.2 or 1.8.3 you'll see it works fine.

Comment: I still have one question. On this website it's not working http://demo1798.helpjuice.com/89571-Question-1 Perhaps you know why? I promise this is it, I won't take any of your precious time anymore.

Comment: start by trying to solve the errors droppping on the console ... hit F12 and check them out. Also ... you're using jquery 1.4.2 ... try updating it to a newer version.

Comment: Are you sure you added the code to your script? I've placed the snippet into the console and it works fine for me ...

Comment: I believe that the reason why it didn't work was that I called jquery 2.1.0 and in the footer jquery 1.4.2 was called. Gonna fix that now. As soon as I get higher reputation I'll vote your answer above +1. Incredibly thankful to you!